# How do I make the checkbox work in this Todo List Application?

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a YouTube tutorial to build a Todo List App in React.js. But the issue that I am struggling to fix is that the checkboxes for each todo item won't work, meaning they won't check or uncheck when I click on them. I've watched the video over and over again to try to see where I went wrong, but the app refuses to work the way it should.

The main App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./Header.js";
import todosData from "./todosData.js";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem.js";
import "../styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: todosData
    };
  }

  handleChange = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedTodos = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        }
        return todo
      })
      return {
        todos: updatedTodos
      }
    })
  }
  render() {
    const todoItemComponents = this.state.todos.map(item => {
      return (
        <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="todo-list">{todoItemComponents}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Todo Item Component:

```
import React from "react";

const TodoItem = props => {
  return (
    <div className="todo-item">
      <input type="checkbox" checked={props.item.completed} 
      onChange={() => {props.handleChange(props.item.id)}}/>
      <p>{props.item.text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoItem;
```

JSON File where I import all the data/info for the Todo Items:

```
const todosData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Walk the dog",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Mow the lawn",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Make your bed",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: "Cook dinner",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: "Scrub the floor",
    completed: true
  }
]

export default todosData;
```

Comment: Instead of mutating the existing todo object, try making a copy. Change `todo.completed = !todo.completed;` to `return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed }`

Comment: @deadcoder0904 .map does not clone the objects *inside* the array.

Comment: @cbr thanks got it so added as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `handleChange` as follows:

```js
handleChange = id => {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      todos: todos.map(todo => {
        if (todo.id === id)
          return {
            ...todo,
            completed: !todo.completed
          };
        return todo;
      })
    });
  };
```

Here we are not mutating the `completed` property rather passing in a new object.

Comment: @OliverBelfort weird i gave u a working example. it works in a codesandbox.io. try copy/pasting it :) if it still, doesn't work share link here & i'll show u the result :)

Answer (score 0):

This works as well:-

```
  handleChange = id => {
      const updatedTodos = this.state.todos.map(todo => { 
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed;
        }
        return todo;
      });
      this.setState({todos:updatedTodos})
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to chnage your handleChange, I made you a tiny example : https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-architecture-omgxm